# Array reads whitespace and control char

Tags: arrays, controls, whitespace, fgets, alphabetical

```
char str[100];    
fgets(str,100,stdin);
int i;
int alpha=0;    
int space=0;
int cntrl=0;
while(str[i])
{
     if(isalpha(str[i]))
     {
        printf("%c is an alphabet\n",str[i]);
        alpha++;
     }
     if(isspace(str[i]))
     {
        printf("%c is a whitespace\n",str[i]);
        space++;
     }
     if(iscntrl(str[i])) 
     {
        printf("%c is a control character\n",str[i]);
        cntrl++;
     }
}

printf("You have %d alphabet\n",alpha);
printf("Your input has %d whitespace\n",space);
printf("Your input has %d control character\n",cntrl);
```

Even after I did not use whitespace it always shows one whitespace also control char I think it is something about array size. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
while(str[i])
```

Correct it to:

```
while(str[i++])
```

Your complete code:

```
char str[100];    
fgets(str,100,stdin);
int i=0; // initialize here
int alpha=0;    
int space=0;
int cntrl=0;
while(str[i++]) // increment after each loop
{
    if(isalpha(str[i]))
    {
        printf("%c is an alphabet\n",str[i]);
        alpha++;
    }
    if(isspace(str[i]))
    {
        printf("%c is a whitespace\n",str[i]);
        space++;
    }
    if(iscntrl(str[i])) 
    {
        printf("%c is a control character\n",str[i]);
        cntrl++;
    }
}

printf("You have %d alphabet\n",alpha);
printf("Your input has %d whitespace\n",space);
printf("Your input has %d control character\n",cntrl);
```

Comment: what issue? You can try ASCII values to fix that

Comment: when I inputted a string in example "asd 0 897 2*/-" program should say your input has 3 whitespace but instead of this it says 4. Always says +1 whitespace

Comment: You can try *str[i]==' '*, instead of using *isspace(str[i])* inside *if* loop